# CS50 cash, don't understand code given by the problem

Tags: c, cs50

I want to understand the code give by the problem set and try to figure it out from there. I can't even start solving the problem since I don't understand the code given. I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around all these return operators and the calculation method for figuring out the cents for quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.

The code should, when I write the code in the todo and return sections, then prompt the user to ask how many cents are owed with an output of "Cents owed: ". It should also return the least amount of coins needed for cents owed using the greedy algorithm.

Main is already implemented but calls to functions that aren't implemented, including `get_cents()`, `calculate_quarters()`, `calculate_dimes()`, `calculate_nickels()`, and `calculate_pennies()`.

I have an idea of using division to find the cents. I'd divide the cents the user inputted by 25 since that's the biggest being the quarter. Then it would return a positive integer. Additionally, I would do cents owed - 25. I would use that number to divide by 10 being the dime to find how many dimes I need to use and return a positive integer. I would keep moving down the stack until I reached pennies. I don't know how I'm gonna implement this yet but is my thought process in the right place?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_cents(void);
int calculate_quarters(int cents);
int calculate_dimes(int cents);
int calculate_nickels(int cents);
int calculate_pennies(int cents);

int main(void)
{
    // Ask how many cents the customer is owed
    int cents = get_cents();

    // Calculate the number of quarters to give the customer
    int quarters = calculate_quarters(cents);
    cents = cents - quarters * 25;

    // Calculate the number of dimes to give the customer
    int dimes = calculate_dimes(cents);
    cents = cents - dimes * 10;

    // Calculate the number of nickels to give the customer
    int nickels = calculate_nickels(cents);
    cents = cents - nickels * 5;

    // Calculate the number of pennies to give the customer
    int pennies = calculate_pennies(cents);
    cents = cents - pennies * 1;

    // Sum coins
    int coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

    // Print total number of coins to give the customer
    printf("%i\n", coins);
}

int get_cents(void)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

int calculate_dimes(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

int calculate_nickels(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

int calculate_pennies(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are right, but I'll just reiterate for others who might have not read your question thoroughly:

The idea is that each function should return the most coins (of a specific type) for a balance, but not go over. For example, `calculate_quarters(76)` should return `3` because 3 quarters make 75 cents and the next increment would have to be 100 cents.

Here's the coding part though: in C, dividing integers always returns an integer, so `76 / 3` will **not** return 25.3333... because 25.3333... is not an integer. Instead, the decimals will be truncated, so `76 / 3` evaluates to `3`. Notice that this will always round down the number.

In your case, this functionality makes the programming easier. Instead of explicitly rounding down, you can simply divide `cents` by the coin's value. Here's an example of the completed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_cents(void);
int calculate_quarters(int cents);
int calculate_dimes(int cents);
int calculate_nickels(int cents);
int calculate_pennies(int cents);

int main(void) {
  // Ask how many cents the customer is owed
  int cents = get_cents();

  // Calculate the number of quarters to give the customer
  int quarters = calculate_quarters(cents);
  cents = cents - quarters * 25;

  // Calculate the number of dimes to give the customer
  int dimes = calculate_dimes(cents);
  cents = cents - dimes * 10;

  // Calculate the number of nickels to give the customer
  int nickels = calculate_nickels(cents);
  cents = cents - nickels * 5;

  // Calculate the number of pennies to give the customer
  int pennies = calculate_pennies(cents);
  cents = cents - pennies * 1;

  // Sum coins
  int coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

  // Print total number of coins to give the customer
  printf("%i\n", coins);
}

int get_cents(void) {
  int cents = 0;
  scanf("%d", &cents);
  return cents;
}

int calculate_quarters(int cents) { return cents / 25; }

int calculate_dimes(int cents) { return cents / 10; }

int calculate_nickels(int cents) { return cents / 5; }

// NOTE: "cents / 1" is the same as "cents", so no need for division here
int calculate_pennies(int cents) { return cents; }
```

PS: For convenience, I also wrote `get_cents()`. That function has nothing to do with this answer.